# How to Implement Line Graph in xamarin iOS , Xamarin android

Tags: .net, graph, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am working on Project using Xamarin cross-platform in one module i have to implement a line graph with curves.[image: Here is example of graph which i need]

- I check Oxyplot but due to lack of Documentation i cant use it out if
  some have example on Oxyplot please provide
- Also tell me any other library which should free or open Source for Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

I do have a suggestion for you, unfortunately it is not an open source chart control, but it is a well supported solution in active development.

[SciChart](http://www.scichart.com) have just released [Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android bindings](https://www.scichart.com/scichart-ios-android-xamarin-v2-released/) for their iOS/Android chart library. This has lots of documentation and tutorials to get started.

[image: Xamarin Charts]

It should be quite easy to create a bell curve like your picture by using a line chart (FastLineRenderableSeries) and the dot can be represented by EllipseAnnotation. Customization of the axis is also possible to remove gridlines, hide the YAxis etc...

Take a look below at the resources we provide.

- [Xamarin iOS Chart Tutorials](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/v2.x/Tutorial%2001%20-%20Linking%20SciChart%20DLLs.html)
- [Xamarin Android Chart Tutorials](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/Xamarin%20Tutorial%2001%20-%20Adding%20SciChart%20libraries%20as%20dependencies.html)
- [SciChart.Xamarin.Examples source code on Github](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Xamarin.Examples)

I will say as a disclosure I am the MD of SciChart. If you have any questions feel free to ask!